# Program flash back in the begin when I use the "vector" or other dynamic array

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-code, gdb

Program flash back in the begin when I use the "vector" or other dynamic array.
I use the vscode with gcc 6.3.0 and gdb 8.2.
I can't debug or break point because the exe crash in the begin without any Error.

I try to change the gcc/gdb to version higher or lower,it's not effect.
But it works in vs2017,But I want it works in gdb,too.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
class Something{
    int id;
};

int main() {
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    vector<Something> something;
    //Something *somethings = new Something[num];
    for (;;) {
        if (_kbhit()) {
            if (_getch() == 27) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So your program crashes before it even hits `int num;`?

Comment: @Tas Yes,any breakpoint is not effect.I thought something wrong with the compiling

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with what you have there. Should work on Windows and not compile anywhere else.